# regarding the use of input().split() with 3+ items

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a program that deals with user input and I came across a situation where I needed multiple returns under one `input()`, at first I didn't know what I was doing when I was getting a value error until I looked up how to do it, which it showed me and worked fine with 2 inputs with `input().split()`

```
class userinput():
def __init__(self, name,lista,listb,listc,listd):
    self.name=""
    self.lista=lista
    self.listb=listb
    self.listc=listc
    self.listd=listd






def set_lists(self):
    print("Do you want to create lists")
    decision = input()       
    if decision == "yes":   
        print("how many lists would you like to create?(up to 4)")
        decision2= int(input())
        if decision2 == 1:
            print("what would you like the list to be named")
            self.lista=input()
            print("you have created 1 list, with the name:"+ self.lista)                                         

        elif decision2 == 2:
            print("what would you like your lists to be?")
            self.lista,self.listb=input().split(",")
            print("You have created 2 lists with the names," + self.lista ,self.listb)

        elif decision2 == 3:
            print("what name would you like your first 2 lists to be")
            self.lista,self.listb = input().split(",")
            print("finally, the name for your third")
            self.listc = input()
            print("you have created 3 lists with the names," +self.lista,self.listb,self.listc)
        elif decision2 == 4:
            print("what name would you like your first 2 lists to be")
            self.lista,self.listb = input().split(",")
            print("finally, for your last 2 lists") 
            self.listc,self.listd=input().split(",")
            print("you have created three lists with the names of," +self.lista,self.listb,self.listc,self.listd)
        else:
            print("quitting")
            return

    else:
        print("quitting")
```

**My Question**: it seems as if it isn't necessary to use 2 `input().split()` for 4 inputs, Is there anyway to clean that up?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing `print().split()`. In fact I believe that that produces an error (unless you are using Python 2.x, which seems unlikely due to `print` being used as a function).

Comment: @sweeneyrod I meant input().split(), thanks for that correction

Comment: I was referring to this line - `print("finally, for your last 2 lists").split(",")`.

Comment: @sweeneyrod Although... `print(foo).split(',')` == `print ((foo).split(','))`

Comment: @Izkata only in Python 2.x

Comment: @Izkata In Python 2.x, where `print(spam)` == `print (spam)` == `print spam` (unnecessary parentheses). But not in Python 3.x.

Comment: @sweeneyrod wow, don't know how I put that part there

Comment: @Nabla The OP seems to indicate it's not erroring, so yes, this is python 2

Comment: the print().split() was accident, I meant input().split()

Comment: @Izkata I don't know, I've seen lots of example code that doesn't actually run without error!

Comment: @Izkata It is likely Python3 because of the print usage as function and `input` instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: this is python 3 however, that isn't my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a, b, c, d = raw_input("what name would you like your 4 lists to be\n").split(',')
```

`split` can split string into more than two parts.

Comment: although raw_input is python 2.x, what you said about split(',') actually does work for multiple, you only have to use it in that way once and it works for 2+

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems, and a lot of duplication here. An approach with a couple of improvements:

```
decision = input("Do you want to create lists?")
if decision.lower() in ("y", "yes"):
    list_count = int(input("How many lists?"))
    names = input("Enter list names (separated by commas):").split(",")
    if len(names) != list_count:
        raise ValueError("Expected {0} names, got {1}".format(list_count, 
                                                              len(names)))
    self.lists = {name: [] for name in names} # dictionary of empty lists
    print("Created {0} lists.".format(list_count))
```

(Note that Python 2.x uses `raw_input`).

`split` creates a list of as many items as the string could be split into, unless constrained by a second, optional argument `maxsplit`:

```
"a,b,c".split(",") == ["a", "b", "c"]
"a,b,c".split(",", 1) == ["a", "b,c"]
```

Comment: in the future im going to add to the function to detect if there is already lists created.Also, they return to specific instance variables, its not as if im creating multiple lists, all im doing at the moment is returning names for the lists, unless that isn't what you mean by "duplication"? or are you describing my format?

Comment: At the moment you're storing the list name strings in hardcoded attributes e.g. `self.lista`. It would be better to store them in a list `self.list_names`, so that you can have a variable number, or, as I have done, actually use a dictionary `self.lists` to allow easy access to the lists later. By duplication I meant the repeated code in your `if: elif:` block for `decision2`.

Comment: eventually, yes im going to implement dictionaries, but this is all I have done at the moment. Im still working on it, and your example does make it much better, im still quite new as you can see I tend to stick to basic if-else

Answer (score 1):

I think this code would be a bit cleaner.

```
    print("Do you want to create lists")
    decision = input()       
    if decision == "yes":   
        print("how many lists would you like to create?(up to 4)")
        decision2= int(input())
        print("What would you like the lists named?")
        listnames = input()
        lists = listnames.split()
        print("you have created %i lists with the following names: %s"%(decision2, ",".join(lists)))

    else:
        print("quitting")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do this:

```
def set_lists(self):
    print("Do you want to create lists")
    decision = input()       
    if decision.lower().startswith("y"):   
        print("how many lists would you like to create? (up to 4)")
        decision2 = int(input())
        if decision2 == 1:
                print("what would you like the list to be named")
                self.lists = [input()]
                print("you have created 1 list, with the name:"+ self.lists[0])                                         

        elif 2 <= decision2 <= 4:
            print("Enter your lists' names, seperated by commas")
            self.lists = input().split(",")
            if len(self.lists) != decision2:
                print("You didn't enter the right amount of names!")
            else:
                print("You have created {} lists with the names {}".format(decision2, ", ".join(map(str, self.lists)))

        else:
            print("quitting")

    else:
        print("quitting")
```

And then do `self.lists[0]`, `self.lists[1]` etc. rather than `self.lista`, `self.listb`.

Comment: self.lists(a,b,c,d) all refer to instance variables which point to the object I created to hold them

Comment: @TimLayne Then either change the method name to something like `get_lists`, or change `lists` in my example to `listnames`.